# Diskspace info from a remote server, multiple drives in one string no CR LF

Tags: powershell, space, disk

I want to get a remote server's disk drive and current diskspace info (for drivetype 3, no CD's or removables) in a single string for inclusion in a server inventory spreadsheet (a status snapshot).

The following code:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -Computer <servername> -Filter "Drivetype='3'"|
  select driveletter,
         @{Name="Capacity (GB)";Expression={[math]::round(($_.Capacity/1GB),2)}},
         @{Name="FreeSpace (GB)";Expression={[math]::round(($_.FreeSpace/1GB),2)}}
```

Gives me output like this:

```
driveletter   Capacity (GB)            FreeSpace (GB)
-----------   -------------            --------------
C:            50                       38.89
E:            309.99                   26.28
P:            10                        5.95
```

I would prefer it to look like this, all on one line so I can easily stuff it in a spreadsheet:

```
C:\38.89/50 E:\26.28\309.99 P:\5.95\10
```

But I'm unsure of how to get it on a single line.

Comment: You've got 5 backslashes and one forward slash in your desired output.  Really?

Comment: Picky ;-) Just threw them in as readable separators. "\" as it relates to  drive prompts and / representing a disk space fraction like 1/4 etc. What do you suggest?

Comment: If it's what you really want, it's fine with me!

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = ''
Get-WmiObject win32_volume -computer $env:COMPUTERNAME -filter "Drivetype='3'" | % {
    $result += '{0}\{1}\{2} ' -f $_.driveletter, [math]::round(($_.FreeSpace/1GB),2), [math]::round(($_.Capacity/1GB),2)
}
$result.trim()
```

recommended alternative:

```
(Get-WmiObject win32_volume -computer $env:COMPUTERNAME -filter "Drivetype='3'" | % {'{0}\{1}\{2}' -f $_.driveletter, [math]::round(($_.FreeSpace/1GB),2), [math]::round(($_.Capacity/1GB),2)})-join' '
```

Comment: I would avoid appending to a string. Simply echo the formatted strings inside the `ForEach-Object`, assign the output to a variable (`$result = Get-WmiObject ...`), and join the resulting list (`$result -join ' '`).

Comment: thanks for the help. why would you join an array vs appending a string?

Comment: Better performance. Probably won't matter in this context, but it's good practice.

Comment: That works like a charm people. Thanks so much. Always impressive the amount of knowledge out there people are willing to share. I'll try and dive into the syntax and see how that works now. Cheers!